# list comprehension does not work with sparse dataframe + never ending groupby and apply computation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I have been stuck for few days on a perhaps easy problem with python (I am a new user). I will report here a simplified version of the issue, considering a very small dataframe (df). In the simplified world the codes work, while with the big df normal operations, like slicing df by column, do not work anymore.

1) Consider a (5x2) df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1432, 1432, 1433, 1432, 1434],
                   'b': ['ab152', 'ab153', 'ab154', np.nan, 'ab156']})

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df.b, sparse=True)

type(df2)

[out] pandas.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame

df2['a'] = df.a

df2 = df2.groupby('a').apply(max)[df2.columns[:-1]].to_sparse()
```

all works fine here. In plain text, I'd like to create a dummy matrix according to a specific column and then remove duplicates in the index by using, in this case, a max function (other functions could be used according to the purpose). 'Sparse' is necessary for memory efficiency reasons (the number of zeros is relatively very high).

Moreover, if I want to extract column 'b', I just write

```
df['b']
```

and it works.

2) In my more complex case I have roughly 5 million rows and 3 thousands cols. I apply the same set of codes.

```
dummy_matrix = pd.get_dummies(big_df.b, sparse=True)

type(dummy_matrix)

[out] pandas.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame

dummy_matrix['a'] = big_df.a

dummy_matrix = dummy_matrix.groupby('a').apply(max)[dummy_matrix.columns[:-1]].to_sparse()
```

But the last line of code never ends and does not provide any error message.

Moreover, If I want to select column 'b' in this case I get an error as in the following:

```
In [81]: dummy_matrix['b']

Out[81]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)

    688                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,

    689                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)

--> 690             printer.pretty(obj)

    691             printer.flush()

    692             return stream.getvalue()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in pretty(self, obj)

    407                             if callable(meth):

    408                                 return meth(obj, self, cycle)

--> 409             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

    410         finally:

    411             self.end_group()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in _default_pprint(obj, p, cycle)

    527     if _safe_getattr(klass, '__repr__', None) not in _baseclass_reprs:

    528         # A user-provided repr. Find newlines and replace them with 
p.break_()

--> 529         _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)

    530         return

    531     p.begin_group(1, '<')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)

    709     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""

    710     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()

--> 711     output = repr(obj)

    712     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):

    713         if idx:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.pyc in __repr__(self)

     62         Yields Bytestring in Py2, Unicode String in py3.

     63         """

---> 64         return str(self)

     65 

     66 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.pyc in __str__(self)

     42         if compat.PY3:

     43             return self.__unicode__()

---> 44         return self.__bytes__()

     45 

     46     def __bytes__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.pyc in __bytes__(self)

     54 

     55         encoding = get_option("display.encoding")

---> 56         return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')

     57 

     58     def __repr__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/sparse/series.pyc in __unicode__(self)

    290     def __unicode__(self):

    291         # currently, unicode is same as repr...fixes infinite loop

--> 292         series_rep = Series.__unicode__(self)

    293         rep = '%s\n%s' % (series_rep, repr(self.sp_index))

    294         return rep

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __unicode__(self)

    897 

    898         self.to_string(buf=buf, name=self.name, dtype=self.dtype,

--> 899                        max_rows=max_rows)

    900         result = buf.getvalue()

    901 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in to_string(self, buf, na_rep, float_format, header, length, dtype, name, max_rows)

    962         the_repr = self._get_repr(float_format=float_format, 
na_rep=na_rep,

    963                                   header=header, length=length, dtype=dtype,

--> 964                                   name=name, max_rows=max_rows)

    965 

    966         # catch contract violations

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in _get_repr(self, name, header, length, dtype, na_rep, float_format, max_rows)

    991                                         na_rep=na_rep,

    992                                         float_format=float_format,

--> 993                                         max_rows=max_rows)

    994         result = formatter.to_string()

    995 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in __init__(self, series, buf, length, header, na_rep, name, float_format, dtype, max_rows)

    146         self.dtype = dtype

    147 

--> 148         self._chk_truncate()

    149 

    150     def _chk_truncate(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in _chk_truncate(self)

    159             else:

    160                 row_num = max_rows // 2

--> 161                 series = concat((series.iloc[:row_num], series.iloc[-row_num:]))

    162             self.tr_row_num = row_num

    163         self.tr_series = series

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, copy)

    752                        keys=keys, levels=levels, names=names,

    753                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,

--> 754                        copy=copy)

    755     return op.get_result()

    756 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, 
verify_integrity, copy)

    803         for obj in objs:

    804             if not isinstance(obj, NDFrame):

--> 805                 raise TypeError("cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame 
object")

    806 

    807             # consolidate

TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

What is the difference between the simpler and the more complex case? Why in one case the code works, while in the other it does not? Could it be related to dtypes? I checked in both case and dtypes are the same for each col so I don't think the issue resides there. Moreover, do you think the two issues, i.e. list comprehension problem and never ending comoutation, are related? I hope yes -> 1 solution for two problems.

Your help would be very appreciated and I am willing to give more details if necessary. Many thanks.

Comment: There was at least one bug related to sparse formatting (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10818) so you might make sure you've updated your python to the latest version and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, your comment was indeed very useful. I tried the same set of codes in python 3.5.1 (I was working with python 2.7 before) and slicing here works. Nevertheless, the never ending computation after the command dummy_matrix = dummy_matrix.groupby('a').apply(max)[dummy_matrix.columns[:-1]].to_sparse() is still there. Would you have any idea why it is so? Thanks.

Comment: It's probably not this, but the first thing I'd try is to isolate `to_sparse()` from the rest of the command, to make sure it's definitely `to_sparse()` that's causing problems.  Then if it is, I'd try `to_sparse()` on a smaller chunk (say 10% of your data) to see if it's a memory issue.

Comment: Thanks. After one day the computation in the end worked in the new python version. However, I noted another problem: with sparse df, the command I wrote doesn't work properly in the new version since it produces just nan, while with core normal df it works (I tried this with the small example I mentioned above). In the old version, the code worked even with sparse objects (always just in the small example). Would you have any idea what's going on between the 2 versions? I think there are some problems with these sparse objects.

Comment: To be clearer df2 =df2.groupby('a').apply(max[df2.columns[:-1]].to_sparse() produces a NaN df in Python 3.5.1, while it produces the desired binary df in Python 2.7. Any clue?